# How to compare 2 CSV files in powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, opencsv, export-csv

I'm trying to compare 2 CSV files with logs info in (logs_all, logs_new)
format:

[image]

I want to add the rows they don't exist in logs_all from logs_new

```
$csv1 = Import-Csv $csvLogs_all -Delimiter "`t"
$csv2 = Import-Csv $csvLogs_new -Delimiter "`t"

$end     = $csv1.Count
$count   = 0
$diffobj = @()

# testtable is the name of the column, adjust it to your column header name
if($csv1.time[$count] -ne $csv2.time){
   $diffobj += $csv2[$count]
}

$count++
}until($count -eq $end)
Write-Host "chekking logs"
$diffobj | export-csv $csvLogs_all -NoTypeInformation
```

but this isn't working well, can some help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [Compare-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/compare-object) cmdlet.

The cmdlet does the following:

> The `Compare-Object` cmdlet compares two sets of objects. One set of
>   objects is the "reference set," and the other set is the "difference
>   set."
>
> The result of the comparison indicates whether a property value
>   appeared only in the object from the reference set (indicated by the
>   `<=` symbol), only in the object from the difference set (indicated by
>   the `=>` symbol) or, if the `IncludeEqual` parameter is specified, in both
>   objects (indicated by the `==` symbol).

In other words, it compares two objects and tells you the differences.

To compare two CSV files you can run

```
$file1 = import-csv -Path "C:\temp\Test1.csv" 
$file2 = import-csv -Path "C:\temp\Test2.csv" 
Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property ColumnName -IncludeEqual
```

Comment: thank you!
and how can i add the difference to file1?

Comment: You can add content to a file using the `Add-Content` cmdlet. E.g. if you want to add the result to `$file1`, just run `Compare-Object $file1 $file2 -property ColumnName -IncludeEqual | Add-Content $file1`

Comment: if i run this i got an error:
Add-Content : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{time=19/04/2018 12' does not exist.
At line:1 char:71
+ ... $file1 $file2 -property ColumnName -IncludeEqual | Add-Content $file1

Comment: My bad, I thought `$file1` contained the filename. Try instead to write `Add-Content -Path "name_of_your_file.txt"`